# Too Many "or" statements (javascript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators, logical-or

I am creating a simple math program with 6 different problem types. I want the program to randomly display one of the 6 types, but some of the problems should appear more often.  I use a weighted array, but after the problem type is selected from the weighted array I am having trouble figuring out which problem type it was without using 10 or more "or" commands inside of an if statement.  Here is a simplified version:

```
//shuffle array of 10 integers to get a random value
var rand_10 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
fisherYates(rand_10);

//Set weightedProb
weightedProb[0] = probType[0];
weightedProb[1] = probType[0];
weightedProb[2] = probType[0];
.
.
.
weightedProb[8] = probType[0];
weightedProb[9] = probType[1];

theProblem = weightedProb[rand_10[0]];
if(rand_10[0] == 0 || rand_10[0] == 1 || rand_10[0] == 2 || rand_10[0] == 3 ||rand_10[0] == 4||rand_10[0] == 5||rand_10[0] == 6||rand_10[0] == 7||rand_10[0] == 8){
  //do something
}else if(rand_10[0] ==9){
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: here is a javascript Fisher–Yates Shuffle http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: `if(rand_10[0] >= 0 && rand_10[0] < 9) { } else { }`

Comment: If you switch the if, it gets easier: `if (rand_10[0] === 9) {/*do something else*/} else {/*do something*/}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would a simple range comparison (`>` and `<`) be what you are after?

e.g.

```
if(rand_10[0] >= 0 && rand_10[0] <= 8){
  //do something
}else if(rand_10[0] == 9){
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! As I wrote below, I was never trained formally so there are some gaps in my knowledge.  Thanks for filling this piece in, it's very simple and useful!

Comment: @user877011 If you are after a good tutorial to Javascript, try the [Mozilla Dev Centre page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), and then when you get comfortable with that, read the [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/).

Comment: I'd also recommend (Code Academy)[www.codeacademy.com].

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this (note indexOf isn't supported in some IE versions):

```
if ([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].indexOf(rand_10[0]) > -1) {
}
```

This is assuming the value isn't always a range and you need granular control.

Answer (score 1):

why don;t you want to write so?

```
if(rand_10[0] >= 0 && rand_10[0] <= 8){
  //do something
}else if(rand_10[0] ==9){
  //do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was never trained formally so I have gaps in my knowledge, this is very simple and useful though!

Answer (score 1):

`arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

```
if (rand_10[0] in arr) {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a switch statement:

```
 switch(rand_10[0]) {
   case 0:
   case 1:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
   case 8:
     // do something
     break;
   case 9:
     // do something
     break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use a function that generates weighted random index like this:

```
function weightedRandomIndex(weights) {
    var sum = 0, i, x, n=weights.length, rnd;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        sum += weights[i];
    }
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*sum);
    for (i=0, x=0; i<n; i++) {
        x += weights[i];
        if (x > rnd) return i;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to specify the weights to pick your array index:

```
var idx = weightedRandomIndex([9,1]);  // 9 to 1 chance for index 0 over index 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I actually use a function to create the random weighted index but I thought it would be harder to read  and it wasn't directly related to what I was asking, so I just wrote a list instead of putting the function in my question.  Thanks though!